# clearcase config spec to select greater revision of two labels

Tags: version, config, clearcase

I am trying to make a Clearcase config spec that will select a file based on the greater revision number when that file has 2 labels I want.

Example:

`file1.c; rev 1 ---> PR438
file1.c; rev 2 
file1.c; rev 3 ---> PR433`

The "basic" config spec of:

`element * PR438
element * PR433`

would choose file1.c; rev1 since this label is first specified in the config spec.

What I want is to choose file1.c; rev 3 without having to analyze the label ordering of every file to properly order a config spec.

Basically, I want a rule that says choose PR438 and PR433 and if a file has both labels, use the file with the highest revision number.

Comment: To provide additional context here is my situation: I more or less inherited an existing development environment with an existing Clearcase setup.  Numerous modification have been made using metadata labels to indication which change tracker they are associated with.  I am trying to select a handful of changes in candidate view to test out the changes.  I want to specify the half dozen or so set of labels in a config spec, but I fear some of the changes might have occurred on the same file and I want to be sure I choose the latest revision of a file for any file having multiple labels.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I want a rule that says choose PR438 and PR433 and if a file has both labels, use the file with the highest revision number.

This isn't [how a config spec uses selection rules](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc%2Fc_bcfg_hwcfgwrk.htm).

If the naming convention of those labels is properly done, the highest (most recent) version will always by `PR438`.
That means selecting `PR438` first, then, as a fallback, selecting `PR433` is enough.

What you could have tried is to select first versions which have both labels.
Even if the [config spec syntax](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc%2Ftopics%2Fconfig_spec.htm) doesn't specify AND or OR operators, that would be:

```
element * {lbtype(PR438)&&lbtype(PR433)}
```

Comment: I do not see the behavior of selecting the most recent version when a rule matches multiple versions of the same file.  Even in the reference you linked to, it states "The version tree of each element is searched for the first version that matches the first rule in the config spec".  This is the behavior I see. I see the order I specify the version label matters in which file revision shows up.

Comment: I have been playing around with using a query to select the files based on examples on the IBM reference site, but I fear that the query returns multiple versions which is an error condition. Example, element * {lbtype(PR438)||lbtype(PR433)} which seems to only work if those labels do not show up on the same file.

Comment: Did you try `element * {lbtype_sub(PR438)||lbtype_sub(PR433)}`? Or `element * {lbtype(PR438)&&lbtype(PR433)` (using `&&` instead of `||`)

Comment: I tried both. The && returns no matches so the next rule is used (a rule to select the latest in the 'integration' branch.  When I use the query in a find command it does in fact return 2 results, one at each revision number the or'd labels are associated with.  I am thinking I am going to have to manually check each label to look for cases where a change has occurred on the same file.

Comment: It is a reasonable question for a real-world problem (the build manager labels versions coming from god knows where, while I independently label versions coming from me. We work concurrently; either one of us can come first: He can check in on top of my version label with his label, and I can make changes on top of his versions and label with my private label. Having either one first in the config spec doesn't describe what I need. Requiring both on the same version doesn't either. LATEST is also not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is a can of worms. In this case, if the NEWER label is attached to the OLDER version you can't use the age of the label type to solve the problem. You're wandering in to "create file-specific configspecs" territory.

So, you'd have to start with the output of something like this:

```
cleartool find -all -version "lbtype(PR438) || lbtype(PR433)" -print
```

From there, you would have to

1. parse it to locate all the duplicate element names (stripping out the version ID's)
2. Take the later version of the duplicate files
3. Put those versions starting on the SECOND line a configspec based on the labels (unless you're OK with not checking out those files, in which case, the "element * CHECKEDOUT" line isn't that important anyway.

Since you're already this far down the path, you could also just build the configspec based entirely on the find output. But that can get unwieldy and unreadable.